# CSS- Change both child and parent on hover

Tags: html, css

So I have two classes: `parent` and `child`.
`parent` class is basically a Square and `child` class contains the text within the Square. I am trying to change
the background color of `parent` and text color of `child` on hover over parent. This is what I have so far,which only changes the `parent`'s background color:

```
.parent:hover {
    background-color: #FFCC00;
}
```

I tried this as well but it didnt help:

```
.panel-body:hover .child {
    background-color: #FFCC00;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Edit: Since none of the solutions are working. I am adding the HTML code piece.

```
<div class="parent">
    <span class="arrow1"><i class="left-arrow" role="numerical"></i></span>
        <div class="child ng-binding">
             Child Text needing color change
         </div>
         <div class="child-2 ng-scope">
             No change needed for this text
         </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML as well?  Also, make sure nothing else is targeting this element with more specificity within the CSS.

Comment: If the below answers do not help, it is because you need to post your HTML, as of now your question is un-answerable

Comment: See adding your html makes a big difference ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you want a combination of both of your attempts like so:

```css
.parent:hover {
  background-color: #FFCC00;
}
.parent:hover .child {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.js">
    </script>
<div class="parent">
  <span class="arrow1"><i class="left-arrow" role="numerical"></i></span>
  <div class="child ng-binding">
    Child Text needing color change
  </div>
  <div class="child-2 ng-scope">
    No change needed for this text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. It's not changing the text color on child.

Comment: I am going to remove my answer because it duplicates juants answer, but the fiddle shows it working.

Comment: @user1195192 I created a code snippet using your HTML code and the CSS I provided does as you described, did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just like this:

```
.parent:hover {
    background-color: #FFCC00;
}

.parent:hover .child{
    background-color: #FFCC00;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It's not changing the text color on child.

Comment: If the text-color is not changed after hover, its because of other CSS rules are taking effect instead. You may use your browser's inspector to see what  CSS rules is taking effect and remove it

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
.parent:hover .child { 
   color: #FFFFFF;
}

.parent:hover {
   background-color: #FFCC00;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It's not changing the text color on child.

Answer (score 0):

This one will work fine as you need to do is to use two blocks.

```
.parent:hover 
{
    background-color: #FFCC00;
}

.parent:hover > .child 
{
    background-color: #FFCC00;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this css along with yours this will change the color of child elements while hovering parent div

```
   .parent:hover .child 
    {
    color:#fff;
    }


    .parent:hover .child-2
    {
    color:red;
    }
```